# Construct an invariant mean from an invariant functional

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, locally-compact-groups, topological-semigroups

I am reading a paper, and I got stuck at an implication, which the authors believed to be natural, and hence did not provide a reasoning. Unfortunately, I can not see immediately why that implication is true. Any kind of help/comments are greatly appreciated. The problem with the implication is the following.

Let $(S, \cdot)$ be a locally compact semigroup, and $C_b(S)$ denote the space of all bounded continuous functions on $S$. For any $s\in S, f\in C_b(S) $, the left translate $L_sf\in C_b(S)$ is defined as  $L_sf(t):=f(s.t)$ for each $t\in S$.

A left-invariant mean on $S$ is a functional $m\in C_b(S)^* $ such that $||m||=m(\chi_S)=1$ and $m(L_sf)=m(f)$ for each $s\in S, f\in C_b(S) $, where $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function on $S$, i.e, the constant function $\mathbb{1}$.

It is given/proved that there exists a linear functional $m\in C_b(S)^* $ such that $m(\chi_S)=1$ and $m(L_sf)=m(f)$ for each $s\in S, f\in C_b(S) $.

**Question:** How can we construct a left-invariant mean on $S$, using $m$ ?

A Hint was given to me in the lines of decomposing $m$ into positive and negative parts. I tried using certain manipulations as well, but could not succeed in that. (I understand that it is enough to find a suitable positive linear functional that takes the value $1$ at $\chi_S$.)

Thank you in advance, for the help!

Comment: Are you asking about $\|m\|=1$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, indeed

Comment: Perhaps the functional $m$ constructed by the authors was positivity preserving, i.e.  $m(f)\ge 0$ for any $f\ge 0.$ If this is the case then $m(1)=1$ and positivity implies $\|m\|=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc No, the functional $m$ need not be positive. If it were, as you pointed out here, then $m$ itself would be a left-invariant mean. Instead, the original implication is that if such an $m$ exists, then one can easily(?!) construct a left-invariant mean on $S$.

Comment: Although I do not know the answer, what I would do in order to better understand this problem is to look at some simple examples: In the case $S=([0,1],\cdot)$ the evaluation functional $m(f):=f(0)$ is such a functional (actually it's already a left invariant mean as it is positive, i.e. the special class Ryszard was talking about). However, when changing $S$ to $([1,\infty),\cdot)$ then $m$ cannot be a simple evaluation functional anymore. Then how does the functional $m$ look like and—assuming $m$ is not positive—how can one construct a left-invariant mean from this $m$?